# Change Email Language, Not Based On Running User's Language

Tags: email, scheduled-apex, translation, translation-workbench

I created a scheduled job which sends an email to System Administrator everyday. The scheduled job works in English and Japanese. I created a custom label and used translation workbench to translate the text. When I tested, I switched to both language and made sure that both works fine.

I put the job in a managed package and then installed it on a test environment, using System Administrator account that uses Japanese language. On the next day, an email arrived in Japanese language. So, I switched the System Administrator account's language to English and waited for another email. But the next email was also in Japanese. Then I guessed that System Administrator account doesn't own the scheduled job. Still, I want to send the email in System Administrator's chosen language.

I can retrieve System Administrator's chosen language but I don't know if I could choose to use that language when the executed job send out the email. Is there any good workaround?

This is my sending email class.

```
public static boolean send(String body, String subject, String[] toAddresses) {
    // Define the email
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
    // Sets the paramaters of the email
    email.setSubject( subject );
    email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
    email.setPlainTextBody( body );    
    // Sends the email
    try{
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email}); 
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is where the subject and body be retrieved from custom label.

```
    if (sendEmail){
        String subject = Label.MailSubject;
        String body = String.format(Label.MailBody, new String[] {Label.LinkText});
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, body);
        BodaisSendEmail.send(body, subject, toAddress);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any email template? 
Yes!! We can change language for custom labels used in emails
 For more details please have a look on workaround provided at site: 
https://kksfblog.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/lost-in-translation-an-api-for-dynamically-translating-custom-labels-in-apex/ 
 Hope this will help you in case having same issue...